# How do I export an A5 doc to an A4 pdf without rescaling?

Tags: pdf, ms-word, pdf-generation

I have an A5 sized doc file that needs to be printed, yet the press needs them on A4 sized pages, centered, unscaled. When trying to export it from Office Word, you can adjust paper size, but only the left and top margins are kept and the content is spread in width to fill the paper (text size remains unchanged). I've tried PDF Architect / PDF Creator, but when it's about printing on A4 sized pages, the result is messed up fonts, messed up line wrapping and worse quality images.

Are there any tools that can preserve size, scale (in this case, centered and no scale), font, line wrapping and image quality as well or is it too much to ask from *free* tools? Proprietary tools are no option at the moment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Word has poor options for exporting the PDF

I see some ways to resolve the issue:

1. Change size of paper in Word then manually recalculate and change size of margins *(make like original page is in the center of bigger)*
2. But best solution I see is to find appropriate options for printing device which should print the document *(like "don't resize original doc pages, centered; output page size A4")*
3. Try to emulate printing with http://www.dopdf.com/ (or similar) software. I'm pretty sure that it's possible to "print to pdf" with your requirements and then you got PDF which you can use for printing on real device

Comment: I'm narrowing it down to the second option. The document is around 300 pages with tons of section breaks and different margins. Had we known the press needs unscaled centered A5 on A4 (they're unable to print A5 in A4, as are we) we would have applied the enlarged margins on A4 sized pages to have A5 content on them.

Comment: I've added 3rd option to my answer

Comment: Basically I was thinking in emulating PDF printing as well. In the end CutePDF seems to solve my problems. But anyway, thank you for your help :)